# Proper Update Procedure for ASP.NET WebForms Site

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I did some searching for this but didn't find anything applicable to my situation/question yet. It's basically: recommended procedure for updating an ASP.NET WebForms IIS website. The sites are WebForms .NET v4.5.1 hosted in IIS v10 I believe.

Details: We have a client website where we do not have access to their live/production system and therefore have to go through their IT department to push updates to the site. They basically run a very simple "copy" console application to copy any updated files from their Prestaging, where we have access, to their Live/Prod site. It's basically like doing a copy-paste in Windows Explorer, it's nothing fancy.

This has worked well enough for basically several years, though recently we had an issue where right after they copied the updated files over, the website started getting repeated errors in ELMAH logging in the form of conflicts between App_Web .dll files in the ASP.NET Temp folder (see pic below).
[image: Website App_Web error after update file copy]

This error happened like several times a minute, for any page visited except oddly the Home page, from the time the updated files were copied until we realized it was happening and resolved it by having the client restart the App Pools and Web Apps in IIS.

**So what I was wondering: do you folks have a recommended procedure for updating a WebForms ASP.NET web site?** I proposed to the client that we might've bypassed this error by first stopping the Website, then App Pool, then copying files, then starting App Pool, then starting Website.

Only problem with that is you bring down the site for the public while it is updated. And honestly, this is the the only time since I've been working at this company for two years that we've had this issue with any website for this client (we have 5 different ones now, all WebForms), and we have an update for one of their sites usually every couple weeks. So I'm not sure fully stopping the website is necessary.

For now we're going to check ELMAH when client says they've done the update to make sure everything's ok (I always VISUALLY confirm the update by browsing the website but due to caching I didn't know it was erroring actually).

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Are you deploying source code and a web site, or are you deploying compiled code (ie: web site application). Which model you are using matters. if this is a web site, then just a copy should be fine. If you deploying a web site application, then the site should be stopped before you copy the files, and then you re-start IIS.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal We are deploying compiled code, so yes a web application. We put any updated compiled files (UserControls, CSS/images, our CMS logic which compiles into several different .dll files, etc) on the Prestaging site which we have access to, and they file copy any updated files over to the Prod site which we don't have access to. So you'd recommend stopping the site hey? I kind of figured that'd be the safest route to go but I doubt the client will like that too much. But who knows; I think it's the proper thing to do but it's their infrastructure/site. Appreciate the advice.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal One more question: Would you think just stopping the website, pushing the files, then starting the website is sufficient? Or would you also stop/start the App Pool as well?

Comment: I never had to stop the app pool(s), and a stop of IIS, deploy and then re-start has been 100% working for me for some time. Some suggest that stopping IIS is too "heavy" of a hammer, but I find that less hassle then having to stop both IIS, and then stop all the app pools.  I am quite sure, that starting IIS will re-start the app pools anyway. Regardless, I have 100% success by a simple stop of IIS, deploy the new site (which includes over writing web config). And then simple start of IIS. So in IIS manager, I just stop IIS, deploy, and then start IIS.